# Suggestions to improve loops on calculator?

Tags: java, loops

1. I want to only run the two inner do-while loops if certain conditions are met.If the program is ran, the error messages are always displayed. How would you correct the loops to only run if the conditions aren't met ?
2. The do-while for the entire program repeats the loop depending on the string Answer. If the program is currently ran, the loop repeats but it doesn't allow input for dogName. Only for dogWeight. How do I correct this?

   ```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(" Welcome to Chiecoman's Dog Age Calculator");
    System.out.println();


   //variables for user input
   String dogName;
   int dogWeight=0; 
   double dogAge, humanAge =0;
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
   String answer;

   do{
   // User input begins
   System.out.println("Please enter your dog's name:");
   dogName = keyboard.nextLine();

   System.out.println("Please enter your dog's age (1-16).");
   dogAge = keyboard.nextDouble();
   // do-while loop to repeat until condition is met
   do
    {    
    System.out.println("Error: Age is out of Range");
    System.out.println("Please enter the actual dog age (1-16)");
    dogAge= keyboard.nextDouble();    
    }        
    while (dogAge <1 || dogAge >16);

   System.out.println("Please enter your dog's weight in lbs");
   dogWeight = keyboard.nextInt();
   // do-while loop to repeat until condition is met
   do
   {
    System.out.println("Error: Weight must be greater than zero");
    System.out.println("Please enter your dog's weight in lbs");
   }    
   while (dogWeight <1);
   // how dog age is calculated
   if (dogAge ==1)
   humanAge=15;
   else if (dogAge >=2 && dogAge <=5)
     humanAge = 4 * dogAge +15;
   else if (dogAge >= 6 && dogAge <= 16 && dogWeight <20 )
     humanAge = 4 * dogAge + 16;
   else if (dogAge >= 6 && dogAge <= 16 && dogWeight >= 21 &&
        dogWeight <= 50)
     humanAge = 4.5 * dogAge + 15;
   else if (dogAge >= 6 && dogAge <=16 && dogWeight > 50)
     humanAge = 7.5 * dogAge;
    // displays dog age
   System.out.println(dogName + "'s age in human years is " +
     humanAge);
   // ask user to calculate more dog ages
   System.out.println("Would you like to calculate the age of another" +
     "dog (Y/N)?");
   answer = keyboard.next();
   }
   while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in a do-while the first iteration always happens. While not optimal for the code - you can see how to work around exception condition below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DogAgeCalc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(" Welcome to Chiecoman's Dog Age Calculator");
        System.out.println();


//variables for user input
        String dogName;
        int dogWeight = 0;
        double dogAge, humanAge = 0;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer;

        do {
// User input begins
            System.out.println("Please enter your dog's name:");
            dogName = keyboard.nextLine();
// do-while loop to repeat until condition is met
            boolean firstAgeInput = true;
            do {
                if (!firstAgeInput) System.out.println("Error: Age is out of Range");
                System.out.println("Please enter the actual dog age (1-16)");
                dogAge = keyboard.nextInt();
                firstAgeInput = false;
            }
            while (dogAge < 1 || dogAge > 16);


// do-while loop to repeat until condition is met
            boolean firstWtInput = true;
            do {
                if (!firstWtInput) System.out.println("Error: Weight must be greater than zero");
                System.out.println("Please enter your dog's weight in lbs");
                dogWeight = keyboard.nextInt();
                firstWtInput = false;
            }
            while (dogWeight < 1);

            // how dog age is calculated
            if (dogAge == 1)
                humanAge = 15;
            else if (dogAge >= 2 && dogAge <= 5)
                humanAge = 4 * dogAge + 15;
            else if (dogAge >= 6 && dogAge <= 16 && dogWeight < 20)
                humanAge = 4 * dogAge + 16;
            else if (dogAge >= 6 && dogAge <= 16 && dogWeight >= 21 &&
                    dogWeight <= 50)
                humanAge = 4.5 * dogAge + 15;
            else if (dogAge >= 6 && dogAge <= 16 && dogWeight > 50)
                humanAge = 7.5 * dogAge;
            // displays dog age
            System.out.println(dogName + "'s age in human years is " + humanAge);
// ask user to calculate more dog ages
            System.out.println("Would you like to calculate the age of another dog (Y/N)?");
            answer = keyboard.next();
        }
        while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) You can use a while loop if the condition is not met
(2) You need to skip blank lines

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(" Welcome to Chiecoman's Dog Age Calculator");
    System.out.println();
    
    
    //variables for user input
    String dogName;
    int dogWeight=0; 
    double dogAge, humanAge =0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    String answer;
    
    do{
        // User input begins
        System.out.println("Please enter your dog's name:");
        dogName = keyboard.nextLine();
    
        System.out.println("Please enter your dog's age (1-16).");
        dogAge = keyboard.nextDouble();
        // do-while loop to repeat until condition is met
        while(dogAge <1 || dogAge >16){
            System.out.println("Error: Age is out of Range");
            System.out.println("Please enter the actual dog age (1-16)");
            dogAge= keyboard.nextDouble(); 
        }
    
        System.out.println("Please enter your dog's weight in lbs");
        dogWeight = keyboard.nextInt();
        // do-while loop to repeat until condition is met
        while(dogWeight <1){
            System.out.println("Error: Weight must be greater than zero");
            System.out.println("Please enter your dog's weight in lbs");
            dogWeight= keyboard.nextInt(); 
        }
        // how dog age is calculated
        if (dogAge ==1)
        humanAge=15;
        else if (dogAge >=2 && dogAge <=5)
            humanAge = 4 * dogAge +15;
        else if (dogAge >= 6 && dogAge <= 16 && dogWeight <20 )
            humanAge = 4 * dogAge + 16;
        else if (dogAge >= 6 && dogAge <= 16 && dogWeight >= 21 &&
                dogWeight <= 50)
            humanAge = 4.5 * dogAge + 15;
        else if (dogAge >= 6 && dogAge <=16 && dogWeight > 50)
            humanAge = 7.5 * dogAge;
        // displays dog age
        System.out.println(dogName + "'s age in human years is " + humanAge);
        // ask user to calculate more dog ages
        System.out.println("\nWould you like to calculate the age of another dog (Y/N)?");
        answer = keyboard.next();
        keyboard.skip("(\r\n)");  //to skip blank lines
    }
    while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your weight input is taking at the inside of your do-while loop as below.

```
    bool initialWeightInput=true; // to avoid run into error message on first iteration
    // do-while loop to repeat until condition is met
    do
    {
      if(!initialWeightInput)
        System.out.println("Error: Weight must be greater than zero");

      initialWeightInput=false;
      System.out.println("Please enter your dog's weight in lbs");
      dogWeight = keyboard.nextInt();
    }    
    while (dogWeight <1);
```